# unit of timespan of command simin in matlab

Tags: matlab

Can anyone guide me that what is the unit of the parameter 'timespan' of simin command in matlab.

```
 [t,x,y1, y2, ..., yn] = sim(model,timespan,options,ut)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can consider it to be any units you choose, provided that you make all your other variables and parameters consistent with this choice.

For example if you were modelling a simple DE like:

```
d2x/dt^2 = ax + b dx/dt + c
```

You may use "x" in meters and "t" in seconds, which would imply "a" was given in sec^(-2), "b" in sec^(-1) and "c" in meters/second^2.

But it would also be perfectly valid to take "x" in km and "t" in years, provided that you also gave constants a, b and c (and initial conditions) in appropriate units.

In other words, it's not so much a question of right or wrong units in a dynamical system like this, it's really just a question of consistent or inconsistent units.

Comment: In my system the code is: Tstop=60; options=simset('SrcWorkspace','current'); sim('pid',Tstop,options) I have implemented PID controller in simulink and I have defined Tstop for that. Suppose I assume Tstop to be in secs; But if I use tic and toc to find total time of simulation of controller its giving me 0.19 secs. I am giving 60 secs to controller for working; but the total simulation time for controller comes out to be 0.19 secs. How can this be possible? guide me.

Comment: Yes you're confusing processing time with simulation time. In general simulations don't run in "real time". For example, if you have a very fast computer then 60 seconds worth of simulation of a particular system may run in one second. On the other hand, if you had a very slow computer then 60 seconds simulation of the exact same system may take a week. Simulation time is unrelated to real time. I've got a calendar on my desk that covers one year, it took 2 minutes to print, how can that be? Hopefully it's obvious that there's no relation between those two things.

Comment: k sir...Just clear me one more thing Suppose I have two controllers fuzzy implemented in simulink in ode14x with fixed step size and PID implemented in simulink in ode45 with variable step size. The PID controller after 9000 iterations converges to specified value and has simulation time of O.19 sec. While  fuzzy converges after 51 values and has simulation time of 2 secs. Which would be better and on what basis? guide me.

Comment: The controller that used the lowest run time would typically be the best in terms of computation power to implement, while the one that converged in the least time in the simulation (not to be confused with run time or real time) would give the best performance if cpu horsepower is not an issue. With the data you give it's not really possible to say conclusively which is which. Firstly your run time involves simulating both the controller **and** the system, and since you're using different solvers for the system in each case we can't really compare the controller cpu times in isolation. ...

Comment: Secondly the iterations to converge doesn't tell us the time to converge in the simulations as we don't know the step sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your great help....Sir the last thing the reason for using different solvers was; PID was not converging in ode14x while Fuzzy not in ode45. So I was forced to change solver. Do you have any idea why fuzzy is not working in ode45 Or PID in ode14x. I searched it but found no good reason for it. Guide me. Thank you very much for your time.